# Processing multiple transactions very fast

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, sending, transaction-input, output

Let's say I run an automated script, with the main purpose to send transactions as fast as possible.

I want to send one transaction with 5 BTC to one address and a transaction with 2 BTC to another.

My own bitcoin wallet has 2 transaction inputs, one with 3 BTC and one with 7 BTC. 
How do I spend the transactions the fastest way?

1. Spend the 5 BTC first having 7 BTC as input, get the change of 2 BTC returned and send this 2 BTC to another address.
2. Spend the 2 BTC first with 3 BTC input, spend 5 BTC with 7 BTC input.

Does order actually matter if I want to send transactions as fast as possible? I was assuming that due to the confirmation time, an optimized transaction order will have an impact on speed of the transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to send one transaction with 5 BTC to one address and a transaction with 2 BTC to another.

The fastest (and cheapest) way to do this is with a single transaction.

Many transactions have 2 outputs, one being for change, but it doesn't need to be for change, and doesn't need to be limited to 1 or 2 outputs either.

Take this transaction for example, it has about 2 dozen outputs: https://blockchain.info/tx/df9ba42c44d25df13d3bdba0994b98b97d8c22293daf0c27e8e5d9b4e21c5906

[image: Trnasaction]

Total fee, just 0.00483272 BTC